# Benefits of injecting antivirus inside browser

Tags: web-application, malware, privacy, web-browser, keyloggers

Some antiviruses propose you to use their browser plug-ins. For instance, [Avast SafeZone propose you reactive defend by checking signatures of keylogers/malware/spyware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113313/safezone-keyloggers-malware-spyware-protection/113315#113315) etc.

But, *what's the benefit of `browser + embeded antivirus plugin` over `browser + separate antivirus`?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the file gets scanned in the browser while downloading. This way you can block malware **before** it's correctly installed on the system.

Most AVs are only able to check for viruses **after** they've been installed to the system and had the time altering it.

[This isn't always the case though.](http://www.howtogeek.com/239950/dont-use-your-antivirus-browser-extensions-they-can-actually-make-you-less-safe/)
Sometimes your browser also leads the downloaded file automatically through your installed AV.

Comment: thanks for answer! May you provide more details about when browser consider to download web page through antivirus and when not please?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk You don't - download - webpages. You only request them. For files, it depends on the add-on/browser and it's configuration. Fireclam for example tests always, like in most cases.

Comment: O'Neil my bad, instead "download web page" I was going to say "execute web page". So do chrome or firefox ever check web page for malware before executing it (means have a chance to check for viruses *before*)? Or you must to install plug-ins?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk Web-pages don't really contain malware directly. There are browser exploits like e.g JSDB; browsers implement protection against it, but not always by scanning. Rather by blocking, blacklisting, and updating.  1) https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/ 2) https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2013/01/11/protecting-users-against-java-vulnerability/ 3) https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox/